# Eclipse Javascript Editor with Code Completion

Tags: eclipse, cordova, eclipse-plugin

Am looking for a plugin that will allow me to have code completion is my phonegap .html file and also highlight the javascript tags. I have installed the JSDT plugins but can't seem to have the code highlighting/autocomplete. It highlights only the HTML but doesn't seem to work for the scripts inside the `<script>` tag.

Comment: Which HTML editor are you using?  And don't answer: "Eclipse."

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look in eclipse at

Help -> Install Software 
Work with... Select your eclipse version (e.g. juno)
In the selection box below scroll to the entry "Web, XML, Java, ... " and expand it.
Select 
Eclipse Java Web Developer Tools
Eclipse Web Developer Tools
Eclipse XML Developer Editors and Tools
JavaScript Development Tools
Web Page Editor

and then Next to install them.

Now you should have HTML, JS syntax highlighting and code completion.